# HTML, CSS and jQuery selectors's riddle

Tags: html, css, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to choose the second inner div without changing the HTML using CSS 2 cross-browser support?

```
<div>
    <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                   <div></div>
                   <div></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add class or ids to the div ?

Comment: used to this div > table > tr > td > div{here style }

Comment: There's only one inner div. There are a hundred ways to select this div, why don't you tell us what the constraints are? Are there going to be more than one inner divs? Are there going to be nested divs? Is the outer div contained in other structures that could interfere?

Comment: This is what classes and id's were designed for, you need to add some specificity to your html or your going to come across CSS problems with styles on elements that shouldn't have.

Comment: @RohitAzad `div div {…}` — simpler

Comment: @VladimirStarkov this is not simpler it's diffrent

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for the mistake...

Comment: This is why it's a riddle... because CSS3 allows it without changing the HTML

Comment: If you're asking in terms of jQuery selectors, then CSS2/CSS3 browser support becomes irrelevant because jQuery will fill in the support for you. Are you really asking in CSS selectors instead?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I wanted to use the selecors of jQuery 1.5

Comment: @lionheart: Doesn't matter what version - jQuery supports most CSS2 and CSS3 selectors in all versions.

Comment: @lionheart If you want to use jQuery 1.5 then there should not be any issue with css3 . nth-child was introduced in jQuery 1.1.4 . This has nothing to do with CSS. They have their own implementation.  Even then for the sake of riddle I updated my answer.

Comment: You are right... And I voted you for your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div div:nth-child(2)").css ( "CSS GOES HERE" );  // index starts from 1
```

---

```
$("div div:eq(1)").css ( "CSS GOES HERE" );;  // index starts from 0
```

This will work in all browsers regardless of the fact browser supports css3 or not.

**EDIT**
As mentioned the above code will work even if the browser supports only **css2** , but if it is only for puzzle then

```
div  div:first-child + div
```

This will affect **only second div** inside main div without use of css3. [ first-child is not css3 ]

Comment: This is the answer... It was just a riddle... Thare are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

try this selectors, any will work fine:

```
  div table div { ... }
```

or

```
  div table tr td div { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use an adjacency selector

```
div + div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kudoslabs/rysys/

reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this selector

```
div div + div {
       …
}
```

**[Demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/4116671)**
[image]

I achieve this result with these css rules:

```
div {
    padding: 5px;
    background: yellow;
}

div div + div {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to find inner div using jquery selector then here is code that might help

```
var innerDiv = $('table').find('div');
```

and for outer

```
var outerDiv = $('table').parents('div');
```

regards.